# How to add custom route in Angular JSS ? Domain/<Page>/<id>

Tags: jss, custom-route

We are working hybrid headless SSR approach.

The pages have a header and footer from Sitecore with wrapper angular components as shown in the image.

We should pass the id of the article from the wrapper component to another through a custom route using node SSR.

Any thoughts?

[image: Article Landing page]

[image: Article Detail page]

Answer (score 3):

I achieved this using wildcard-item in sitecore.

I created like below,

[image]

Below list of working urls.

http://a-custom-route.com/articledetail/id1

[image]

http://a-custom-route.com/articledetail/id2

[image]

**Note:**

- Please handle your content retrieval logics as per id display in the URL(/articledetail/**{id}**).
- Handle this logic in a component and map with wild card item.
- Display not found article as well.
  Ex: [http://a-custom-route.com/articledetail/{notfoundid-or-empty}](http://a-custom-route.com/articledetail/%7Bnotfoundid-or-empty%7D)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I should create a custom pipeline processor to override the Item resolver. Considering this is an angular JSS application, should i also place dll for this override?

Comment: @GayathriSriram You don't need to create any pipeline for resolve. This is Sitecore OTB. Above my answer is a JSS application. Its working.

Comment: Seems interesting. Since I'm new to jss wanted to know if they are any mapping logic you did for wild card items that would be helpful. All our items will be the bucketed items

Comment: No mapping logic, Its OTB. Check Sitecore documentation here https://doc.sitecore.com/en/users/100/sitecore-experience-platform/create-a-dynamic-url-with-a-wildcard-item.html